# Using git on a Mercurial Queue Directory

Tags: git, mercurial, mercurial-queue

I have got a folder containing a list of diff files in a Mercurial queue (mq) format and I want to apply these patches.

At first I tried `git am --patch-format=hg -- "path/to/files/"`, but this gave me the error `Patch is empty.  Was it split wrong?`.  I tried `git am --continue`, hoping this is a non-stopping error, but it complains `Patch does not have a valid e-mail address.`.  I then typed `git am --abort`.

I also tried to use `git am --patch-format=hg -- "path/to/files/*.diff"` and `git am -- "path/to/files/*.diff"` but these complained that there is `No such file or directory`. Is there a better git tool that I must use, or am I misunderstanding how `git am` works?

Comment: The patches do not contain all meta information like an author. Try to convince git am to use your default author or supply author information another way.

Comment: alternatively simply use the good ol' patch tool itself: `patch -p1 < path/to/patch`

Comment: why don't you apply them in mercurial and them convert to git?

Answer (score 0):

[`git am`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.3/git-am.html) is command for applying patches and sequences of patches from e-mails, either mbox or Maildir format, while MQ is just set of "naked" pathches, not wrapped into e-mails (with additional metadata in e-mails) - in "easy case" or hg-repository (if patches are versioned).

You **have not expect** this format as applicable for `git am` ("Apply Mail") command

If you want to apply patches from (plain unversioned) Mercurial Queue, you *must* to see at [`git apply`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.3/git-apply.html) carefully (AFAICR, it can apply only single patch per command, but TBT!!!)